# Discord py - Overwrite permissions not affecting the channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to create a channel with specific permissions.
Everything seems to work just fine, yet when I go to the settings of the newly created channel, it didn't seem to have any effects. Neither the permission syncing, nor the overwrites affected the channel. Why is that ?
My code:

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=arg.title())
            if role is None:
                role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=arg.title())
            channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=arg.title())
            if channel:
                if channel not in category.voice_channels:
                    await channel.move(category=category, beginning=True)
                await channel.set_permissions(role, connect=True, view_channel=True)
                await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, connect=False, view_channel=False)
            else:
                overwrites = {
                    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False, view_channel=False),
                    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True, view_channel=True)
                }
                channel = await category.create_voice_channel(arg.title(), overwrite=overwrites)
            await channel.edit(sync_permissions=False)
```

PS:
I want to set to False the permission syncing and I only found a way to do it after the channel was created.
Is there a way to do it when creating ?

Comment: If you are already overwriting the permissions, `permissions_synced` will already be false, you don't need to edit it again

Comment: Didn't know that thanks! Do you also know why my bot isn't creating the channel with the proper rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the wrong keyword in

```
channel = await category.create_voice_channel(arg.title(), overwrite=overwrites)
```

`overwrite` is not a keyword arg for `category.create_voice_channel`

The correct usage would be:

```py
channel = await category.create_voice_channel(arg.title(), overwrites=overwrites)
```

References:-

- [`category.create_voice_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_voice_channel#discord.CategoryChannel.create_voice_channel)

Comment: OK, I thought the library would warn me about using a named parameter that doesn't exist. Thank you!